# How to stop others from inserting variables in url

Tags: wordpress, var

Hackers tend to insert variables in a website through the URL. Normally no problem, though the website has plugins that output these variables in the HTML.

I don't want that to happen. How can I stop the server (in that case my WordPress website) from accepting variables in the URL?

I have some idea's to achieve this, though I don't really know what's best:

1. The best would be to remove `?var=somevar` from the URL (don't know how to with nginx config)
2. Or to simply change the "=" to "-"; then we can see the things hackers or bots try but the variable wont be correct or go through in the HTML

Anyone has a clue how to do this?

I've been searching with Google for two hours for I thought it would be a hot topic to NOT accept `?vars=from-anyone`. Anyhow there is little to no documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can put some server side conditions. By using 'init', or 'wp_head' hook you can add some conditions / validation to check the GET value is authenticate or not. If not then redirect to home url or any other page.
2. But I think the best way to change the url pattern. You can use this function "[add_rewrite_rule](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_rewrite_rule/)"
   you can use this pattern www.example.com/custom-page/get-value
   instant of www.example.com/custom-page?var=get-value

Comment: 1) How can I actually block/check variables? In generall all variables.

2) I did a lot of research for using the add_rewrite_url, even made an plugin where it flushed permalinks so they should work, however I did not manage to rewrite ?random=example to an non-working url where the variable stops being an variable.